# How do you make label text show above radio inputs?

Tags: html, css, forms, radio-button

For some reason when I try to do `label>` How Many Times do you Play Per Week?`<label` right above my radio inputs, the text from the label doesn't show up. When I try it in any other place such as at the end of the radio inputs it works. It only doesn't work before the radio inputs.

```css
.bcontainer {
  height: 800px;
  width: 550px;
  background-color: rgba(245, 245, 220, .95);
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  border: 2.5px solid black;
}

label {
  display: block;
  margin: 15px;
  color: black;
  font-family: verdana;
}

fieldset {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

input {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  border: 1px solid black;
  min-height: 2em;
}


}
.align {
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: unset;
  margin: 0 10px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="hcontainer">
  <h1 id="title">Game Type Survey</h1>
  <p id="description"><em>Thank you for your response!</em></p>
</div>
<div class="bcontainer">
  <form id="survey-form" action="https://register-demo.freecodecamp.org">
    <fieldset>
      <label id="name-label">Username: <input type="text" name="username" id="name" placeholder="username" required>
            </label>
      <label id="email-label">Email: <input id="email" type="email" name="address" placeholder="email" required>
            </label>
      <label id="number-label">Age: <input id="number" type="number" min="21" max="120" name="age" placeholder="21">
            </label>
      <label>Which Wallet Do You Use? <select name="wallet" id="dropdown" required>
              <option value="">Select Wallet</option>
              <option value="1">MetaMask</option>
                <option value="2">Coinbase</option>
                <option value="3">Wallet Connect</option>
              </fieldset>
              <fieldset>
              <label>How Many Times do you Play Per Week?</label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="#oftimes" class="align" value="1">0-1</label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="#oftimes" class="align" value="2">2-7</label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="#oftimes" class="align" value="3">8+</label>
```

Comment: Pls post some code! How are we supposed to help you without seeing it.

Comment: Sorry I didn't know how to put code in. I updated it.

Comment: Pls use code snippets! No one, at least not me, are going to copy paste this code into their editor and run it.

Comment: Pls see [this](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Ok, I didn't know sry.

Comment: No problem you can edit it now. Many new comers make this mistake, it’s not only you.

Comment: That’s why we reviewers are there to help people like you.

Comment: Also you are supposed to keep the title in question format.

Comment: When I try to put the snippet in it says there's too much code.

Comment: Ok, I will update the title. Thanks!

Comment: You are posting too much code then. Pls see [How to create minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: because this CSS `input { width: 100%; ...` easy to see on any browser inspector ( key is F12)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't closed both the `<label>` and `<select>` elements before it. Close those and it should work, like this:

```html
<label>Which Wallet Do You Use?</label>
<select name="wallet" id="dropdown" required>
  <option value="">Select Wallet</option>
  <option value="1">MetaMask</option>
  <option value="2">Coinbase</option>
  <option value="3">Wallet Connect</option>
</select>
```

I recommend finding out how to 'auto-indent' on your code editor of choice, or otherwise get in the habit of keeping perfect indentation, as issues like these are really easy to spot and avoid when the code is indented correctly :) It also makes everything a lot tidier and easier to work with!